# Is it safe to close SQLite db more than once?

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite with python.

My code for closing SQLite DB is as follows.

```
def close(self):
    if not self.closed:
        self.db.closeDB()
        self.closed = True

def closeDB(self):
    self.cursor.close()
```

I have one variable 'closed' not to close the db twice. Is this variable necessary? What would happen if I call the close() function twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's save. Just make sure, that you don't want to operate on a closed connection.